# Can you bypass a category's behavior in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, objective-c-category

I have a category on UINavigationBar, the drawRect function of which draws a custom logo in the nav bar. There is one view controller in my app which i would *not* like to draw the custom logo for.

Is there a way to bypass the category's drawRect function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope; you can't.   Or, you can (through swizzling), but you shouldn't.   Namely, you are modifying system behavior, which is a good way to either cause crashes in the future or potentially have your app rejected.

Typically, if you want to customize a class's behavior, you do so by subclassing and using instances of the subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Use two different subclasses of UINavigationBar and put the category on one of the two subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing something wrong, against the HIG, if you need to do this.

Matt Gallagher wrote an article about invoking the ['supersequent' implementation](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html) which may be used in this case.

Note that this not the proper way to achieve such a thing, even if it works now it's very likely to break in the future, I'd advise not to use such techniques!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem you will no longer face in ios5 as using a category to "override" drawRect in the navigation bar is not supported any more.

You should look into the new UIAppearance changes, or as Daniel says, use multiple subclasses of UINavigationBar.